# Code generation: Custom controller templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, controltemplate, asp.net-mvc-4

To start off, I'm using Asp.Net MVC 4, and I've modified my solution to contain the CodeTemplates folder by following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx) tutorial. (I think my issue might be MVC related?)

[image: code_templates]

I've replaced the code in the Ajax grid template with a with my own JQgrid-template, which was fine for getting my project started. But I'm having trouble creating completely new controller templates (well the having them show up in the create new controller menu)

[image: add_controller_modal]

any ideas?

**Update**

I've taken a few stabs at using the scaffolding feature, but it's not exactly what i had in mind (although it does work like expected. I watched a video by steve sanderson on the topic that was quite informative), any way to get my custom views/controllers inside the add controller gui?

Comment: I agree with you, I don't prefer the command line approach that .net scaffolding is taking so I created my own extension that uses a GUI and T4 to allow you to scaffold almost anything in any project, not just MVC.  If you are interest in trying it out, you can download it [here](https://www.t4awesome.com/).  Full Disclaimer, I sell licenses for using the more advanced features but have a forever free community edition that allows basic scaffolding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as my understanding of your problem goes, you cannot manage two controllers within one .ps1 file, which corresponds to your "AddController" directory. 
You have to use the Package Manager and issue a command like

```
Scaffold CustomScaffolder <choose-name>
```

This will generate another subfolder below CodeTemplates with the name . From there, you open and edit t4 files like you did with your existing one.

More info [here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/)