# Best way to regenerate ASP.NET MVC 4 default controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm curious if there is a best practice to regenerate a new MVC 4 controller?

**What I've done:**

1. Generated the controller `BookingController`
2. Realized I need to run a migration to drop an attribute in the `Booking` model
3. Wish to update the auto generated `BookingController` with these changes automatically

Is it just a case of deleting the views and controller and starting again? I'm scared this might, for some reason, not let me generate a new one?

Comment: Did these changes even affect your controller?

Comment: to regenerate template you must hv .tt file in your solution.. this can be achieved by mvcscaffolding see here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998855/mvc-4-custom-controller-templates .

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - they shouldn't if the design was truly loosely coupled, thus the up vote.  If changing a **property** on a domain model forces a change in a controller template, you're doing it wrong :)